# How to output the current line number in a Liquid template?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

In Shopify Liquid Templates, for debugging purposes, is it possible to output the current line number of the template file? (similar to the `__LINE__` variable in PHP)

Answer (score 1):

No. Shopify compiles all Liquid into a single huge HTML string which it then dumps out to browsers.

You can always use HTML comments in your liquid to debug... they work fine.